# Leightweight task management with Slack integration

Tags: productivity, slack

I'm looking for a lightweight task management solution that fullfils the following requirements:

1. Slack integration (create tasks right out of Slack)
2. Tells me on a regular basis which tasks are still open. It needs to nag me, and it never grows tired of nagging me until it's #done.
3. Email integration (create new tasks via email. optional as I could forward mails a Slack channel)

Comment: There are any number of web services that will do this.  Are you looking for that or for something on your own machine?

Comment: a web service would be preferred so that colleagues can use this as well without needing local installation, but a local solution would make me happy too.